# Q: How can I calculate this Delta Dirac integral ??

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I'm trying to integrate the following Delta Dirac integral: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x). \delta(x^2-c^2t^2)dx $$ where $c$ and $t$ are arbitrary constants, could you help me ?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about use one property that says $$ \delta(g(x))=\sum_a \frac{\delta(x-a)}{|g'(a)|} $$ but I don't if I can indeed factor $x²-c²t²$ in $(x+ct)(x-ct)$ and just apply this, because this way we would get 2 simple integrals.

Comment: What do you obtain from $\delta(g(x))=\sum_a \frac{\delta(x-a)}{|g'(a)|}$ ?

Comment: Because I saw the proof of this property and I guess I didn't understand it at all. The book expanded $g(x)$ in taylor series until the first derivative term and after this they set $g(a)=0$ and $g'(a)$ different of $0$, something in this way.

Comment: If I use this property I get $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x). \delta(x^2-c^2t^2)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x). \delta((x-ct)(x+ct))dx $$  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ( f(x). \frac{\delta(x-ct)}{2|ct|} + \frac{\delta(x+ct)}{2|-ct|} )dx  $$

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x). \frac{\delta(x-ct)}{2|ct|} +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x).\frac{\delta(x+ct)}{2|-ct|} dx  $$ = $$\frac{f(ct)}{2|ct|} + \frac{f(-ct)}{2|-ct|} $$ is it right ?

Comment: @KalebRoncatti: yes. I was updating my answer while you wrote your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using what you have in your comment:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\delta\!\left(x^2-c^2t^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\left[\frac{\delta(x-ct)}{2|ct|}+\frac{\delta(x+ct)}{2|ct|}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\frac{f(ct)+f(-ct)}{2|ct|}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I unhid the final line since Kaleb had it correct in his later comment.

Comment: Thank you, I just was only in doubt about this.

Comment: So if $t=0$ the integral is not defined?

Comment: I think that if $t=0$ we cannot use this property, because when $t=0$ we have $g(x)=x²$ and the proof of the property use taylors approach and it asks $g'(a)$ to be different of $0$. The roots of $x²$ are coincidents and equal to $0$, but the derivative applied in the root is $0$ and it can't happen.

Comment: I think the proof still holds but I must say it goes beyond my intuition!

Comment: hehehe, I guess I don't have too much intuition about this too, I only proved it to you following the property conditions.

Comment: @KalebRoncatti Interesting question anyway. I guess it is related to a hyperbolic PDE?

Comment: No, this is an isolated exercise, we were trying to learn the basics and the properties of the Dirac Delta.